# i am a noob in frontend, so Automated generated html page is not being rendered properly when sent through mail, it runs properly in live server

Tags: html, css, html-email, html-templates

[this is how it looks when rendered on live server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tUeo.png)

[it is distorted when automated response is triggered and
the template is being sent via postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZv0e.png)

note:- 'The reason this is written in 'inline css' because gmail doesnt consider outline css, it renders the html in a plain form, it can only render inline css.' for those who are not aware.
this is the code, sorry i am completely new to this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>message_generation</title>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body
    style="
      font-size: 15px;
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      font-family: 'Montserrat';
      padding: 1%;
      padding-bottom: 1%;
      margin: 7px;
      display: flex;
      align-self: center;
      align-items: center;
    "
  >
    <div
      class="outer"
      style="
        background-color: rgb(255, 238, 238);
        height: 90%;
        padding-top: 1%;
        padding-bottom: 1%;
        padding-left: 1%;
        padding-right: 1%;
        width: 100%;
      "
    >
      <img
        src="./crackle.png"
        href="https://crackle.tech/"
        alt=""
        srcset=""
        style="
          height: auto;
          width: 150px;
          align-self: center;
          padding-bottom: 20px;
          padding-top: 8px;
          padding-right: 8px;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          margin: auto;
          align-self: center;
        "
      />
      <div
        class="inner"
        style="
          font-size: 15px;
          background-color: white;
          font-family: 'Montserrat';
          padding-bottom: 5%;
          margin: auto;
          border: 1px solid black;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          width: 100%;
          align-self: center;
          align-content: center;
          flex: content;
        "
      >
        <p style="padding-left: 2%; font-size: 12px">
          Dear ${1}, <br />
          Your bank account details <br />
          have been updated to <br />
        </p>
        <br />
        <div
          class="contain"
          style="
            background-color: #e3e4e5;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            min-width: 100%;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 30%;
            gap: 8px;
            height: 30%;
            padding-top: 13px;
            padding-bottom: 8px;
            align-self: center;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            padding: none;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
          "
        >
          <div
            style="
              display: grid;
              grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
              gap: 8px;
              align-items: center;
              font-size: 13px;
              white-space: wrap;
              padding-left: 20px;
              flex-wrap: wrap;
            "
          >
            <p style="margin: 0; flex-direction: row">
              &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Bank Name &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
              &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;:
            </p>
            <p style="margin: 0; flex-direction: row; font-weight: 600">${2}</p>
            <br />
          </div>
          <div
            style="
              display: grid;
              grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
              gap: 8px;
              align-items: center;
              font-size: 13px;
              white-space: wrap;
              padding-left: 20px;
            "
          >
            <p style="margin: 0">
              &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Acc. No&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
              &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; :
            </p>
            <p style="margin: 0; font-weight: 600">${3}</p>
            <br />
          </div>

          <div
            style="
              display: grid;
              grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
              gap: 8px;
              align-items: center;
              font-size: 13px;
              white-space: wrap;
              padding-left: 20px;
            "
          >
            <p style="margin: 0">
              &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;IFSC &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
              &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;:
            </p>

            <p style="margin: 0; font-weight: 600">${4}</p>
          </div>
          <br />
          <div
            style="
              display: grid;
              grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
              gap: 8px;
              align-items: center;
              font-size: 13px;
              white-space: wrap;
              padding-left: 20px;
            "
          >
            <p
              style="
                margin: 0;
                size: 11px;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                flex-wrap: break;
                display: flex;
                align-self: baseline;
              "
            >
              &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Beneficiary Name&nbsp; :
            </p>

            <p
              style="
                margin: 0;
                word-wrap: break-word;
                font-weight: 600;
                width: 80%;
                overflow-wrap: break-word;
                display: flex;
                align-items: baseline;
              "
            >
              ${5}
            </p>
          </div>

          <br />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="regards" style="padding: 7px; font-size: 12px">
          <p
            style="
              margin: 0;
              white-space: nowrap;
              padding-left: 1%;
              padding-right: 3%;
            "
          >
            If the account update was not initiated by <br />
            you, please reach out at

            <a
              href="mailto:support@crackle.tect"
              style="padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 5px"
              >support@crackle.tech</a
            >
            <br />
            <br />
            Thank you, <br />
            Crackle Team
            <br />
            <i style="font-size: 10px"
              >This is a computer generated mail, please do not reply.</i
            >
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 10px">
        You have received this mandatory service notification email <br />
        because it contains important information about your Crackle account.
        <br />
        Crackle Technologies, 9 Raffles Place, #29-05, Republic Plaza, Singapore
        048619
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My guess was that it takes body as an output, and the 'outer' div is crammed inside body?

Comment: You have some invalid attributes and values in your html.  It might be that the browser managed to work around it with a best effort correction, but postman might not do that.  I'd recommend to use an HTML validator and fix the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Email only accepts a subset of web technology. You can't use grid (https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=grid) or flexbox (https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=flex), for example. But you have no need to reinvent the wheel either, there are plenty of techniques out there. If you want a separate automated generator tool, there is not an 'answer' for that, but search for them.